# Objective C - Enabling a button/ or any view after a certain amount of time

Tags: objective-c

This is probably easy but I do not know where to start as I'm still new. I have a button on screen, and when the user taps it, it becomes disabled (I'm using `setUserInteractionEnabled:`).

How do I make it so that the button will automatically enable itself after a certain amount of time (let's say 1 minute)?

Comment: Use any of the several different timer functions -- NSTimer, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, this piece of code should do it:

```
double delayInSeconds = 60.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES
});
```